# Identity Server requires scope, instead of returning all available scopes

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I am in the process of upgrading an Authorization Server from .NetCore 1.1 to .NetCore 2.0

Previously, I could call the "connect/token" endpoint with no "scope" parameter, and the token would include all valid scopes for the client.

Now, the same request returns an "invalid_scope", and I must explicitly define a scope to generate a token.

This is problematic, since we don't want production users to need to change their code whenever we add new valid scopes.  I do not see any documentation about why this change would have occurred.  Is this a bug, a new requirement, or something else?